# Visual Studio for Mac, drag drop from Content Resources folder not working

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, intellisense, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to drag an image "logo.png" into my code, but the drag and drop feature is not working. Every time I need to manually type the command which is a bit cumbersome. On Windows 10, I never faced this issue. Can someone let me know how to fix this on macOS?

As you can see in the image, I'm trying to drag "logo.png" file into index.cshtml but this isn't working.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not supported in Visual Studio for Mac. You could file a feature request - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/visual-studio-for-mac.html?type=idea

Comment: Ohh. Thats too bad.